ESP32 Plus ESP32s3 LovyanGFX
Купил себе такую игрушку как CS01 Plus. Чип видео ST7796U, тачпад FT6336U, Flash 16 Mb, PSRAM 2M.
Никак не могу разобраться как вывести картинку на эран. Нашел на гитхабе скетч с настройками для своего девайса, при помощи которого можно рисовать всякие линии и квадратики - там вроде бы все норм с цветами, я проверял, рисуя всякие фигуры определенных цветов, но вот если попробовать вывести картинку по вот ЭТОЙ инструкции, то получается какая-то фигня:

И картинка из массива из инструкции, rocks_02.h выглядят так же. Настройки конвертора следующие:

Мне еще понравился онлайн-конвертр. А код у меня такой:
#define LGFX_USE_V1         // set to uACse new version of library
#include <LovyanGFX.hpp>    // main library
#include "esp32-hal-psram.h"
#include "C:\Users\madmentat\Documents\Arduino\ArduinoLCD\CS01PLUS\img.h"

// Portrait
#define TFT_WIDTH   320
#define TFT_HEIGHT  480

class LGFX : public lgfx::LGFX_Device
{
lgfx::Panel_ST7796  _panel_instance;  // ST7796UI
lgfx::Bus_Parallel8 _bus_instance;    // MCU8080 8B
lgfx::Light_PWM     _light_instance;
lgfx::Touch_FT5x06  _touch_instance;

public:
LGFX(void)
{
{
  auto cfg = _bus_instance.config();
  cfg.freq_write = 40000000;    
  cfg.pin_wr = 47;             
  cfg.pin_rd = -1;             
  cfg.pin_rs = 0;              

  // LCD data interface, 8bit MCU (8080)
  cfg.pin_d0 = 9;              
  cfg.pin_d1 = 46;             
  cfg.pin_d2 = 3;              
  cfg.pin_d3 = 8;              
  cfg.pin_d4 = 18;             
  cfg.pin_d5 = 17;             
  cfg.pin_d6 = 16;             
  cfg.pin_d7 = 15;             

  _bus_instance.config(cfg);   
  _panel_instance.setBus(&_bus_instance);      
  }

  { 
  auto cfg = _panel_instance.config();    

  cfg.pin_cs           =    -1;  
  cfg.pin_rst          =    4;  
  cfg.pin_busy         =    -1; 

  cfg.panel_width      =   TFT_WIDTH;
  cfg.panel_height     =   TFT_HEIGHT;
  cfg.offset_x         =     0;
  cfg.offset_y         =     0;
  cfg.offset_rotation  =     0;
  cfg.dummy_read_pixel =     8;
  cfg.dummy_read_bits  =     1;
  cfg.readable         =  false;
  cfg.invert           = true;
  cfg.rgb_order        = false;
  cfg.dlen_16bit       = false;
  cfg.bus_shared       = false;

  _panel_instance.config(cfg);
}

{
  auto cfg = _light_instance.config();    

  cfg.pin_bl = 45;              
  cfg.invert = false;           
  cfg.freq   = 44100;           
  cfg.pwm_channel = 7;          

  _light_instance.config(cfg);
  _panel_instance.setLight(&_light_instance);  
}

{ 
  auto cfg = _touch_instance.config();

  cfg.x_min      = 0;
  cfg.x_max      = 319;
  cfg.y_min      = 0;  
  cfg.y_max      = 479;
  cfg.pin_int    = 7;  
  cfg.bus_shared = true; 
  cfg.offset_rotation = 0;

  cfg.i2c_port = 1;//I2C_NUM_1;
  cfg.i2c_addr = 0x38;
  cfg.pin_sda  = 6;   
  cfg.pin_scl  = 5;   
  cfg.freq = 400000;  

  _touch_instance.config(cfg);
  _panel_instance.setTouch(&_touch_instance);  
  }

  setPanel(&_panel_instance); 
 }
};

static LGFX lcd;            // declare display variable

// Variables for touch x,y
static int32_t x,y;

void setup(void)
{
lcd.init();
// Setting display to landscape
if (lcd.width() < lcd.height()) lcd.setRotation(lcd.getRotation() ^ 1);
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.pushImage (0,0,480,320,_Kristi480);
}

void loop()
{
if (lcd.getTouch(&x, &y)) {
lcd.fillRect(x-2, y-2, 5, 5, TFT_RED);
lcd.setCursor(380,0);
lcd.printf("Touch:(%03d,%03d)", x,y);
}
}

Кстати, если собирать проект в нативном онлайн-конструкторе от 8ms.xyz, то все Ок:

То есть, сам девайс не сломан, дело в каких-то настройках. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, откуда идут искажения.
P.S. По совету товарища eri сделал RGB-тест. Вот оригинал, квадратик 40 на 40:

А вот что получилось после конвертации:

Но вот что делать дальше я пока тоже не понимаю, так что буду благодарен за помощь.

По картинке похоже, что в первом случае используется палитра, а должно быть RGB. Возможно где-то в подключаемых файлах задано.

Тут режим конвертации R5G6B5, 16 бит. Я пробовал другие варианты - там либо вообще ничего не работает, либо совсем уж абстрактные картинки на экране, просто какие-то полоски или типа того.

Не видно, где вы это настраиваете. В первом и во втором случае точно одинаково указано? Проблема явно в кодировании цвета.

Подправил текст вопроса. Теперь видно что там режим RGB 565

Кстати, а что значит "палитра" в данном контексте?

Палитра это для гиф. Из фотки извлекается 256 или 16 цветов в массив. Картинка хранится в 8 или 4 бита на точку .  для отображения на лету подставляется индекс цвета из палитры

@eri не только gif, но да, суть такая.

возми квадрат, небольшой 16х16. нарисуй на нем полосы RGB. загони этот квадрат в онлайн конвертор и посмотри какие биты в байте занимают цвета. возможно там RGB 555 или GBR, а может YUV. посмотри нет ли каких префиксов у сгенерированной картинки

Ща попробую и выложу скриншот.

Интересные результаты получились )

После
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

Используйте
lcd.swapBytes(true); 

Это для прозрачных правильных цветов.

В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.
